# how to insert the value of dynamically generated run time textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have one table into database named `card_details` which has two fields `card_number`, `card_value`. I want to create some asp.net application where user enter the value of `card number` in textbox and automatically fetch the respected `card value` into another textbox.

Suppose user has more than one card then we have to give one button (Add More Card). After clicking this button its automatically generate two textboxes on runtime as mentioned my requirement where user can put the `card number` and its finds the `value` in another textboxes. And its also `sum` the `card values`(Gross Total) and show into another textbox.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far and where you are having problems ?

Answer (score 0):

$('#idTextbox').val('type texh whatever you want');

idTextbox: id of the dynamic textbox.

Is this, what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Panel to your page and then in the code behind of your Button use this to add controls dynamically:

```
TextBox dynamicTxtBox = new TextBox();
dynamicTxtBox.Text = "(enter text)";
dynamicTxtBox.ID = "dTxtBox";
Button dynamicBtn = new Button();
dynamicBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(dynamicBtn_Click);
Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamicTxtBox);
Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamicBtn);

private void dynamicBtn_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//your code here
}
```

Similarly you can add another TextBox as your requirement is two boxes.